# Referencing a column in an array perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a file which contains multiple rows and columns of data. I need to read in the file and print when a particular column matches a particular number.

This is what I have below, I currently do not get any results:

```
my $old_flag = 'file1.txt';
my $new_flag = 'file2.txt';

open (IN, "<$old_flag");
open (OUT, "+>$new_flag");

my @data = <IN>;

for (@data) {
    my @old_flag;
    chomp;
    @old_flag = split /\t/, $_;
    push (@records, @old_flag);
}

foreach my $record (@records) {
    if($record[2] == 11125) {
        print OUT "$record[2]\n";
    } else {
        next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `use strict; use warnings;` to your script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably think you are creating a two-dimensional array by doing this

```
push (@records, @old_flag);
```

But in fact you are just pushing values onto a regular array. And here, you think you are accessing a two-dimensional array

```
foreach my $record(@records){
    if($record[2] == 11125) {
```

But in fact, you are just checking the same non-existent array element every loop iteration. You see `$record` and `$record[2]` refer to two different variables. The latter is just the third element of the `@record` array. Which you have never declared. If you had used `use strict` you would have gotten the error:

```
Global symbol "@record" requires explicit package name at foo.pl line 12
```

What you might do to fix it is:

```
push @records, \@old_flag;    # works because @old_flag is a lexical variable
...
foreach my $record (@records) {
    if($record->[2] == 11125) {
```

Here, you are treating `$record` as an array reference, which it is.

You are having these problems because you are not using

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

These two pragmas have a certain learning curve, but they will prevent you from making simple mistakes and typos and will reduce your debugging time.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @TLP. I can't believe I forgot those. I am still having an issue when I try and print the $record. I get things such as ARRAY(0xd23570). Any ideas what is still going wrong here?

Comment: That is an array ref stringified. You must dereference it if you want to print its values. E.g. `print @$record`